# R Find and replace multiple scripts at once

Tags: r, replace

I have several R scripts and my client just wants to change the colours of the graphs.

Is there any way to find and replace all at once instead of find&replace opening the scripts one by one?

I have tried a little tool called [fnr](https://findandreplace.codeplex.com/) with .txt files and it works, but it doesn't with .R files.

Comment: If the tool works why not change the .R extension to .txt?

Comment: Is it possible? can you use txt straight to R as scripts? Just changing .R for .txt?

Comment: Should be ok - they are just text files. But you can change them to .txt run your tool then change them back to .R.

Comment: On linux you could put all the .R files in a folder then `cd "path/to/folder"` then rename the R files as.txt with `rename 's/.R$/.txt/' *.R` , run your tool then chnage the names back. Although you could replace strings more simply (if you are using linux) - quite a few examples on SO

Comment: I'm running Windows and RStudio. Using the trick of just substitute .txt for .R works but when you open the .txt script in RStudio there is no highlighting/formatting of the code functions...

Comment: `Find And Replace` is a nice app that will do the job for you. http://sourceforge.net/projects/findandreplace/

Comment: Find And Replace didn't work either... I will go manual this time, hopefully someone will find the answer in the future.

Comment: in "Find And Replace", did you untick the "exclude binary files..." option in the settings menu?

Comment: Notepad++ offers the ability for find and replace in all open documents and find and replace in files (within a directory, and optionally its sub-directories).

Comment: You can still use `rename` in Windows. ie `rename *.R *.txt` to change all .R files in the current directory from .R to .txt. By changing the extension you do lose some of the functionality of Rstudio but why des this matter - you are just running fnr.exe to find and replace. You can change the files back to .R after. That said, others have offered better methods to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very useful tool called grepWin. It has plenty of options for search and replace. It search subfolders, different types of matches, date filters, etc...

You can download it at https://tools.stefankueng.com/grepWin.html

[image]

Comment: Notepad++ is the easiest method. You can drag the entire folder or files into notepad and go to `Search > Replace` or `Ctrl+H` and be sure to select `Replace All in All Opened Documents`

Answer (score 9):

The `xfun` R package has a few functions to do exactly this (`gsub_file()`, `gsub_dir()`, etc.)

For example, if all your R scripts are in a sub-folder in your working directory, you can simply write:

```
library(xfun)

gsub_dir(dir = "Scripts", pattern = "color = 'green'", replacement = "color = 'blue'")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach using R, where you create a function that finds-and-replaces text in a file and you apply this function to all of the R scripts in your directory.

In the example below, this changes the code `color = 'green'` in any R script to `color = 'blue'`.

```
# Define function to find-and-replace text in a single file
  file_find_replace <- function(filepath, pattern, replacement) {
    file_contents <- readLines(filepath)
    updated_contents <- gsub(x = file_contents, pattern = pattern, replacement = replacement)
    cat(updated_contents, file = filepath, sep = "\n")
  }

# Apply the function to each of the R scripts in the directory
  my_r_scripts <- list.files(path = my_dir, pattern = "(r|R)$")

  for (r_script in my_r_scripts ) {
    file_find_replace(r_script,
                      "color = 'green'",
                      "color = 'blue'")
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's also regexxer: https://github.com/GNOME/regexxer for Linux. RStudio developers seem to be working on a solution also, as documented here (which contains information on a few other approaches): https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2066